# How to clear the console in Java with Windows?

Tags: java, windows-console

I want to clear the cmd Windows console in Java, so I found this code:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cls");
```

But has not worked in any case.

There is another way to solve this problem?

Comment: `cmd /c cls` perhaps.

Comment: Given that java is intended to be cross-platform, there's no in-built way to do this within the API. Whilst there may be ways to achieve this using `exec()` these would only work on Windows (which seems fine, given the scope of your question) - but bear in mind future versions of windows may change the command they use to clear the screen.

Comment: Are you sure that this line is being called?

Comment: As far as cross-platoformness goes, it not too hard to fix that. Just do `exec(cmd)` and have some logic to set the string `cmd` beforehand based on OS